# Word meaning "its meaning stands alone"

Tags: meaning, linguistics, disambiguities

This is a linguistic term I came across recently, but I can't quite remember it - and searching for it is downright impossible!

The word implies that context is not required for a particular word.

"He" or "said" or "the" mean nothing by themselves but "Denied" written on an application doesn't need any further grammatical context. Similarly if you say you passed an exam, and someone replies "ecstatic!" there is no ambiguity; no requirement for the person to say "I am ecstatic" - its meaning stands alone.

Anybody familiar with this term?

Comment: We take these terms to be *self-evident*...?

Comment: Are you looking for a linguistic term or a grammatical one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Other answers seem to have overlooked the fact that you are requesting a term from linguistics. I don't think *axiomatic* is what you're after.

I believe the term you are looking for is *categorematic*.

***Categorematic*** words are "words that designate self-sufficient entities (i.e. nouns or adjectives)" ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncategorematic_term)) or words "that are capable of being employed alone as a term" ([here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/categorematic)).

Merriam-Webster defines ***categorematic*** as "capable of standing alone as the subject or predicate of a logical proposition :  expressing a complete substantive meaning" ([here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/categorematic)).

***Syncategorematic*** words are words "that do not stand by themselves... (i.e. prepositions, logical connectives, etc.)" ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncategorematic_term)).

That fact that these definitions explicitly mention "standing by themselves", "standing alone", and "being employed alone" suggests that they fit what you're looking for.

"Denied" and "ecstatic" are categorematic, while "he" and "the" are syncategorematic.

Comment: Hey! This is a really cool term. Never encountered it before. Thanks! You didn't get the OP's tickmark, so here's one from me: ✓(given because *categorematic* satisfies a quibble I had with *axiomatic*, as that has to be qualified to be applied to terms).

Answer (score 4):

Possibly **free-standing**:

> free-standing adj.  (a) standing alone; not attached or connected to another structure; not supported by a structural framework;  **(b) fig. independent or autonomous; not belonging to a larger entity.**

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/74375?redirectedFrom=freestanding#eid3668113)

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***axiomatic***

> :  taken for granted :  self-evident *an axiomatic truth*
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/axiomatic)
>
> *The term "ecstatic" is axiomatic*
>
> [Google](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=%22word+is+truistic%22&oq=%22word+is+truistic%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...2712.14611.0.14978.19.19.0.0.0.0.542.4607.0j1j10j4j0j1.16.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..3.11.2936.0.DRw0QER_5o8#q=%22phrase+is+axiomatic%22); [Berkeley Law Scholarship Repository](http://scholarship.law.berkeley.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3199&context=facpubs)

Comment: Propositions can be *axiomatic*, but I don't think the concept is applicable to words. Take OP's examples: "*Denied* is axiomatic"? "*Ecstatic* is axiomatic*"?

Comment: @DanBron "The term 'ecstatic' is axiomatic" https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=%22word+is+truistic%22&oq=%22word+is+truistic%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...2712.14611.0.14978.19.19.0.0.0.0.542.4607.0j1j10j4j0j1.16.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..3.11.2936.0.DRw0QER_5o8#q=%22phrase+is+axiomatic%22

Comment: What I quibbled with is only saying "axiomatic" can refer to terms; if you explicitly label the term and then modify it with *axiomatic*, I think that works. So  you'd have to include the cond\struction "the term X is...", or something like it (similar to my comment under the OP). I recommend you integrate that phrasing into your question (and maybe include your google.fr link as further evidence). PS: I am not the downvoter.

Comment: I believe this to be slightly superior to free-standing. I may be wrong, but I think that "free-standing" would imply that such terms must appear in isolation (or that it would at least be preferable). Axiomatic implies that further information is superfluous, I think. As it's also the term that I had lost and wanted to find...

Comment: I don't think *axiomatic* is quite what the OP is after, although they did vote this as an answer. I think the word he/she is looking for is *categorematic*. See my answer.

Comment: @Stumbler Hi, Stumbler. I thought per your comment to my answer that "axiomatic" was the term you had lost and wanted to find. What made you change your mind, if I can just ask?

Comment: @Elian it actually was the word I had been thinking of, and a better alternative to free-standing. I gave you an upvote as well. I think that Silenus' answer may technically be more accurate however.

Answer (score 0):

To be fancy and to use latin terms, use *res ipsa loquitur*.

This phrase means "the things speak for themselves", which is a pretty good fit for what I think you're getting at.

(Source: my latin education)

Answer (score -1):

An ***interjection*** is a word that can stand on its own, without further grammatical context. Usually it is used as an exclamation of surprise or a response to a question, but it can also be used as a statement or command.

Answer (score -2):

**Obviousness** since 'obvious' means : **1**. Easily perceived or understood; apparent. See Synonyms at apparent.
**2**. Easily seen through because of a lack of subtlety; transparent: an obvious political ploy that fooled no one.